# Get real table width in safari when max-width is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

I am using bootstrap and it gives `.table` elements the following styles:

```
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
```

If I put that table into a container which is not wide enough to fit the table's contents, the table will ignore its max width and render wider than the container.

The problem is that **safari does not report the width of that table correctly**. It reports it as if it were 100% of the container.

Open this on chrome and then on safari:
http://jsfiddle.net/6nfotj8j/2/

How can I get jquery to give me the correct width of the table **without** removing the `max-width`?

(side note - this code will go into a jquery plugin, so id like to change/assume as little as possible about the underlying DOM)

**edit**
only affects safari version 7, works as expected in 5

[image: safari reports width as 48!]

Answer (score 0):

Using the inspector in safari you can see its actually ~523px (borders added) and your fiddles prints ~522px which is fine (borders not calculated - change to `outerWidth()` to include borders + padding + margin).

In Chrome - script outputs ~516px and inspector ~518px, again that's correct (borders missing again).

The difference is between how the table renders in the two different browsers - fonts, line-breaks etc...

No problem here (tested also in FF, IE), you are getting the correct actual width of the table.

Comment: you probably don't have safari 7, and I didn't know to specify this when I asked. What version do you have?